# Too afraid to change current company

Tags: new-job, india

I am being underpaid, the salary credit is always delayed, I am paid for like 10 out of 12 months (most of us have delayed payments), and there is no career growth at all. Some team leads and managers always mess up the project and blame it onto developers.

However, the work culture is somewhat better.

Should I change my company or stick to it ?

Comment: You are the only one who can answer that.. Questions regarding advice for a specific choice are off-topic at TWP. But generally, start looking for interviews and new gigs - brush up your CV and put the word out there - you might find other, more interesting/appealing jobs than your current one.

Comment: Where are you located? By location, I mean which jurisdiction are you in. This is very important. And are you a contractor or an employee? What does your contract/employee manual say when you should be getting padi? Wage theft is a very serious issue.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Like, I am able to get off work early, because I have to travel 60 km. Mostly I get sick leaves without much hesitation. etc.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I updated it. However, I dont think there is anything mentioned in the manual about delay of payment. I am a full time employee though

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I dont know. I am very new to the job market. I keep hearing that people get their leaves cancelled.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear they fail to pay you some months? I would start with chasing that legally while at the same time finding a company that does pay me.

Personally I would be gone the first time my company failed to pay my salary regardless of if I was underpaid.

You don't state your country or how difficult it might be to find a new job where you are but I would start my search today.

Comment: This too may be influenced significantly by local culture. In some geographies, companies struggle under COVID-19 restrictions etc to the point where not paying out salaries in full is a survival tactic.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I change my company ?

Normally "Should I...?" questions don't really work on here because they're had to answer definitively and we can't really make decisions for you. But we *can* take you through how you should approach making that decision for yourself.

In this case however I'm going to cheat a bit and start you off with the direct answer:

**Yes, absolutely, run!**

Now on the the more customary part of the answer....

They're currently only paying you 10 out of every 12 months - that means you wage is only effectively 83% of what it's supposed to be **and** you've mentioned previously that the salary is below average in the first place. It sounds as though you're a software developer, which means you have at minimum a decent core of transferrable skills. This makes you potentially employable across a fairly broad range of different companies and even different *industries*. I'm not sure what the job market is currently like where you are but I'm having a hard time imaginging that it's *so* bad that you couldn't find another job somewhere else that's going to pay (at minimum) more than the 83% of your current salary, do so reliably, offer a less stressful working environment and in general massively improve your overall quality of life.

If anything, given by the simple fact that the industry averages are more than you're current wage the chances are very good that you'll be able to find a job that pays *more* than you'd be getting even if your current employer spontaneously stopped messing you around and started paying you every month, on time. Which, spoiler alert, isn't likely to be happening any time soon.

They've had [4 years](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182227/focus-less-on-companys-work-and-more-on-upskilling#comment595052_182228) to get their act together to the point where they can do basic things like pay their employees, that's not a company with teething troubles, or an unlucky moment, it's a badly run one, it might not be circling the drain just yet but it can't be too far away.

There's two sides to every ddebate however, so what's good about staying where you are? Well, you state:

> However, the work culture is somewhat better.

Wow.. that's what we call "damning with faint praise" - if the best you can say about something is not particularly good that speaks volumes. A gunshot wound to the leg is "somewhat better" than one to the head - doesn't mean you'd want either!

So yes, run, run *far* away. And by that I mean polish that CV until it shines and get it fired off to every opportunity listed that you think you could succeed. Once you've escaped your current job I'm almost certain you'll get a fresh perspective, look back and realise how absurd it was that you even questioned whether to leave.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. You too have given me hope. I was so depressed for the past few months. Now, I dont even care, if the question gets closed. I have my answer already. lol

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you work in tech. If so, you should *definitely* change companies!

Now more than ever, you have *lots* of options in front of you! COVID has really changed the landscape, so that even if you live in some weird or remote place, you are no longer limited to the few jobs available in your area. It's almost the norm, now, to work for a company whose office you've never stepped foot in, for a boss you've never met in person! It's become so common that some cities, like my hometown of Tulsa, will *pay you over ten thousand dollars* just to move there and work from home!

Now, regarding your missing paychecks, it is worth checking in with a lawyer or at least some online legal websites before quitting. I wouldn't want to advise you to change jobs if somehow that means you will lose you ability for backpay.

But realistically, if your company isn't paying you now, what makes you think they'll be better about that in future, no matter what you do? When in doubt, ***it is always better to strike out for new horizons than it is to stay and wallow in a job you hate.***

And the best part about looking for a new job is--if you work in tech--you won't even barely need to *try!* All you have to do is just put your resume on every single job site you can find, and the offers will come flying in.

You can even be lazy! Skip the job sites' recommendations. Just do the bare minimum upload you feel like doing. Reuse the same resume over and over again on each upload, with no cover letter or anything else, if you want to, if you don't feel you have the energy or would rather rewatch *Battlestar Galactica* tonight.

Just make sure that whatever you *do* upload includes every single skill and/or software you have ever used in your entire career, from SQL to Excel to Abobe Illustrator. Even if you haven't used something in seven years, these are what will catch the algorithm's attentions, and the more the merrier. (Seriously. Put down "Microsoft Office" if there's enough room to do it.)

Soon you will have more job offers coming into your emails than you could ever realistically respond to. Some of them will suck, and some might require you to brush up your Adobe Illustrator skills a bit. But who cares? It just takes one good job to remake your entire career and *leave these assholes in the dirt, forever!!!*

And even before that final happy moment comes, where you get an email back about that interview you had from a company in Denver, saying they'd *love* to have you on their team, working from the comfort of your own home, I predict that merely having your resume uploaded will make your current job feel less awful! There is nothing that makes a 1:1 with an annoying, selfish team lead more endurable than this thought, going on in the back of your mind, while he goes on and on about some inane thing:

> Just you wait, Trevor! Even as we speak, I'm getting five offers for
> jobs all over the country. By this time next year, you'll be just a
> stain on the road in my rearview mirror.

It will also give you more confidence when going to HR and saying, "You owe me two months' back pay, and I need it NOW. Before summer, before I call my lawyer, and before you pay Trevor. Pay me what you owe me, because if you don't, I'll *leave*. And good luck hiring someone new at a place as shitty as this!"

There's nothing so free as being able to say "take this job and SHOVE it!"

Comment: I was almost certain that the question will be closed (4 flags already), but you made my day. I am from India by the way. One of the stackoverflow members updated it. lol